# How to make my app gets included in the "Open With" or in "Share" for every txt file from file manager?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I've tried all all the found answers about my problem but none answers it. I need my app or app's activity come-up with other apps whenever I want to open any ".txt" file using ES file Explorer or default File Manager. I tried almost all solutions but none worked for me or I couldn't made it working.
In short: When I tap on a .txt file my app should be on the list as "Open With" or/and when I tap Share the app should be there to open that text file.
Please. Help Me.

Comment: can you please post your android manifest

Comment: have you tried to specify intent-filters??

Comment: Please share the manifest file or other relevant portions of the code

Comment: As I said I tried almost all the solutions. here are the latest tries:
<activity android:name=".ViewNote">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.*\\.txt" />
                <data android:host="*" />
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Please anyone with an answer??